# Changed value at [0][1] also changes value at [1][0] ,[2][0] for object list

Tags: c#, object, multidimensional-array

I have a code which copies element into object array. But changing value at a location also changes value of element located at similar index in object array. For example changing value at `[0][1]` also changes value at `[1][0]`, `[2][0]` for object list in C#.

Comment: How did you initialize `newShuffleSet`?

Comment: Where is `k` initialized?

Comment: you are using cloud[k] .......you are not incrementing k

Comment: Added full code you are all can see but it is not working solution yet needs some refactoring

Comment: The code in question throws "An item with the same key has already been added.". Any chance you can create a working example instead?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen :-  Ya I know as i said in my previos comment it needs still to be corrected

Comment: I solved my self this problem using firstSet.Take(3).ToList() which creates new deep copy. without this shallow copy  was happening at this line.   But i need some better solution

Comment: No, it's the right solution. You need a new list. If the list contains more than 3 elements, and you only want the first 3 in that copy of the list, the code is exactly as it should be.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen List has atmost 3 elements. But in the Take(3) case it is required to pass number of elements so i needed here to wright Take(3) instead of Take().  Please would u elaborate more here how to create new list to achieve deep copy here.

Comment: Just call `.ToList()`, this will produce a copy. It will include all the elements, so if you have more than 3, they will all be a part of the copy. However, if the list only contains 3 or less items, you don't need to go through `Take(3)`.

Comment: I dont this so. ToList() creates Deep Copy Just searched google.

Comment: can some one help me here with deep copy

Comment: C# don't understand when to do deep and shallow copy and we also don't have any method like Clone in Perls/Python. We need to implement clone explicitly to do Deep Copy.

Comment: Why did you remove the code? It's going to be much harder for anyone to help you now